# CarouselView with different ContentViews Binding ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I`m trying to convert my CarouselPage to a CarouselView.
In my CarouselPage i have some ContentPages, which i transformed to ContentViews.
Now i added the ContentViews to the CarouselView.

```
<forms:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding ContentViews}">
 <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ContentView Content="{Binding Content}" />/
  </DataTemplate>
 </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</forms:CarouselView>
```

//ViewModel

```
private List<ContentView> _contentViews;
public List<ContentView> ContentViews
    {
        get { return _contentViews; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _contentViews, value); }
    }
public TestVM(){{ContentViews = new List<ContentView> { new Selector(), new TestView() };}
```

It works fine, but i`m losing my databinding.
Now i was wondering how i could bind a ViewModel to the Views in the Carousel View, or if i could bind them to the "Parent" Viewmodel of the Carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution:
I set the Content to the Content of the Views, but the Binding was set outside of the Content of the View.
Now i put the Binding inside the Content of the View which finally works.

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout.BindingContext>
            <viewModels:TestViewModel />
        </StackLayout.BindingContext>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding Colorback}"></BoxView>
        <Label Text="Test" ></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my `ViewModel` I have created my an `ItemSource` of ViewModels this way I can bind different ViewModels to each view in the carousel. Then I create a DataTemplateSelector which handles the matching of Views and ViewModels.

ViewModel Code:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        Views = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>
        {
            new SomeViewModel1(),
            new SomeViewModel2()
            new SomeViewModel3(),
            new SomeViewModel4()
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Views { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModelBase:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

HomeViewSelector:

```
public class HomeViewSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ViewTemplate1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ViewTemplate2 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ViewTemplate3 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ViewTemplate4 { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var tab = (ViewTab)item;
        DataTemplate template = null;

        switch (tab.SelectedTab)
        {
            case CarouselViewTabs.View1:
                template = ViewTemplate1;
                break;
            case CarouselViewTabs.View2:
                template = ViewTemplate2;
                break;
            case CarouselViewTabs.View3:
                template = ViewTemplate3;
                break;
            case CarouselViewTabs.View4:
                template = ViewTemplate4;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        return template;
    }
}
```

Home.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Views"
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Selectors"
             x:Class="WeddingPhotos.Mobile.Views.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ViewTemplate1">
                <v:SomeView1 BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext.ViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeView2">
                <v:SomeView2 BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext.ViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeView3">            
                <v:SomeView3 BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext.ViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeView4">
                <v:SomeView4 BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext.ViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <s:HomeViewSelector x:Key="HomeViewSelector"
                                SomeView1="{StaticResource ViewTemplate1}"
                                SomeView2="{StaticResource ViewTemplate2}"
                                SomeView3="{StaticResource ViewTemplate3}"
                                SomeView4="{StaticResource ViewTemplate4}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>           
            <cv:CarouselViewControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomeViewSelector}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: aaaaaaaa I am going mad please help. All over the web and on this page people use this kind of example: `    <CarouselView ...  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CarouselTemplateSelector}"   />` but whenever I do that I get the error message Cannot assign property "ItemTemplate".... !!! ... what's going on??!!

Comment: What's going on?  You are at the mercy of The Chimps.  Your 'CarouselView' object needs to come from CarouselView.Forms.Plugin and not Xamarin.Forms.  The former has the properties you need, whereas the latter is just a 'chimp placeholder element'

Answer (score 2):

I made a similar solution, but made an extra container for combining ContentView/ViewModel:

Heres the global carouselView:

```
        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding ContentViews}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView Content="{Binding Content}" BindingContext="{Binding ViewModel}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

Constructor of the ContentPage it's viewmodel that is containing the carousel:

```
        public ContainerViewModel()
    {
        _contentViews = new ObservableCollection<ContentViewWithVM>();
        ContentViews.Add(new ContentViewWithVM
        {
            Content = new Page1View(),
            ViewModel = this //Or any other viewmodel
        });
        ContentViews.Add(new ContentViewWithVM
        {
            Content = new Page2View(),
            ViewModel = this
        });
        ContentViews.Add(new ContentViewWithVM
        {
            Content = new Page3View(),
            ViewModel = this
        });
    }
```

Simple container with ViewModel/View

```
public class ContentViewWithVM : BindableObject
{
    public ContentView _content;
    public object _viewModel; //Choose a base viewmodel, object just for reference

    public object ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _viewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            _viewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ContentView Content
    {
        get
        {
            return _content;
        }

        set
        {
            _content = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did great except that normally, your view model should not hold your list of content view (by definition, it should be managed in the view).

What I do is to create my content views in my content page, like that in your xaml.cs :

```
CarouselView.ItemSource = new List<View>
{
    new ContentPage{ BindingContext = myCurrentViewModel},
    new ContentPage{ BindingContext = myCurrentViewModel},
...
}
```

Comment: What does your Xaml look like? Because when i try your approach i still don`t have any Bindings.

Comment: My xaml is the same as yours